Zero set of polynomial is irreducible without algebraic geometry
As an exercise I'm trying for fun, I want to show that the analytic set
$$V\left(z_1 z_2 - z_3^2\right) = \left\{z \in \mathbb{C}^3 : z_1 z_2 - z_3^2 = 0\right\}$$
is irreducible, and I would like to do this without using the techniques and methods in algebraic geometry. Here, an analytic set is irreducible means that it cannot be written as the union of two proper analytic sets.
The strategy that I've come up with to do this involves showing that the the set of regular points $\mathscr{R}$ of $V\left(z_1 z_2 - z_3^2\right)$ is connected. (I know for a fact that if the set of regular points in an analytic set is connected and dense in the analytic set, then it is irreducible.) So all I need to do is work out what $\mathscr{R}$ is and whether it is connected. I have already figured out that $\mathscr{R} \supset V\left(z_1 z_2 - z_3^2\right) \setminus \{0\}$ and so the claim I'm trying to verify is that this containment is actually an equality. In other words, I want to show that there is no open neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ in $\mathbb{C}^3$ such that $V\left(z_1 z_2 - z_3^2\right) \cap U$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^3$. After some searching around, a very concise argument I've come across is that $V\left(z_1 z_2 - z_3^2\right)$ is not locally Euclidean at $0$, and one sees this by using the fact that the map
$$\pi : \mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{0\} \to 
V\left(z_1 z_2 - z_3^2\right) \setminus \{0\}, \quad \pi(t_1 t_2) = \left(t_1^2, t_2^2, t_1 t_2\right)$$
is a $2$-sheeted covering map.
I have verified for myself that $\pi$ is $2$-sheeted, but I haven't managed to work out why $\pi$ is a covering map. In particular, I'm not sure what the open neighbourhoods I need to use are to ensure that points in $V\left(z_1 z_2 - z_3^2\right) \setminus \{0\}$ are evenly covered. Could I get suggestions on what the open neighbourhoods I need to use are, or if there is another way to see that $\pi$ is a covering map? Finally, assuming that $\mathscr{R} = V\left(z_1 z_2 - z_3^2\right) \setminus \{0\}$, it is unclear to me why this set is connected. I was thinking it has to do with the fact that $\mathscr{R}$ is a $2$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^3$, but I haven't been able to come up with a concrete argument. Any suggestions in this regard will also be much appreciated!

Since $\pi$  is a surjective map onto its  image and  $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus\{0\}$  is a connected  space  so is its image too.
Regarding the  evenly covered open  sets:
Let  $(a,b,c)\in V(z_1z_2-z_3^2)\setminus \{0\}$ is given.  WLOG  assume  that  $a\neq 0$ otherwise we would  do the  same  argument for  $b\neq 0$. We know that $z\mapsto z^2$ is  a  2  sheet covering  space from $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}\to \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ so  there is  a  neighborhood  $U\ni a$   which  evenly    covered  via  the  square map.
Put  $G=\{(a,b,c)\in V(z_1z_2-z_3^2)\setminus \{0\}\mid a\in U\}$.  We  claim that  this  $G$ is  the  desired  evenly  covered open  set  around $(a,b,c)$.
With  some  abuse of  notations the   two preimages  of $U$ under the  square map are  denoted by  $\pm \sqrt{U}$ as  open  sets  in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ So  the  square  map  is  a  homeomorphism  between $U$  and its  preimages $+\sqrt{U}$ and  $-\sqrt{U}$. Now  define  $\pm W:= \pm \sqrt{U} \times \mathbb{C}$. Then $\pi: \pm \sqrt{U}\times \mathbb{C} \to G  $  with $\pi(z,w)=(z^2,w^2,zw)$ is  a  homemorphisms so  we  have  a  covering  space  structure
Added: As  it is  indicated in the post the  non  deleted  variete $V$, the  zero  locus of  $z_1z_2-z_3^2=0$, is  not a  manifold. The problematic point is the  point origin.
Here is  an  algebraic  topology  proof of the  fact that $V$ is not a manifold(at origin):
To the  contrary assume that $V$ is  a manifold hence is  a  4 dimensional  real  manifold. Hence  the  relative homology $H_i(V,V\setminus \{0\})$ is  isomorphic to $H_i(S^4)$.(See excision argument and good pair  argument in the  book of  Allen  Hatcher, algebraic  topology).
Here is  a  summary of the  latter two:

Under certain good  condition the  relative  homology $H_i(X,A)$  is  isomorphic to $H_i(X\setminus Z, A\setminus Z)$. This  is  the  excision argument. So  for a  manifold $M \ni p$ the  relative  homology $H(M,M\setminus\{p\})$ is $H(U,U\setminus \{p\})$ where $U$ is  an open chart around p which look like  a  Euclidean  disk  $\mathbb{D} $(In case of  manifold). But  $U\setminus \{p\}$ deformation retract to the  boundary  so  we  have a  good pair $(\mathbb{D},\partial \mathbb{ D})$.


Under  certain  condition on a  good pair $(X,A)$ the relative  homology $H_i(X,A)$ is  isomorphic to $H_i(X/A)$.This is  called   a  good  pair.

Now  we  apply  the  homology  long  exact  sequence for  pairs $(V, V\setminus \{0\})$(See the  book of  Allen  Hatcher)
So  we  have  $$\ldots \to H_2 (V) \to H_{2}( V,V\setminus \{0\})\to H_{1} (V\setminus \{0\})\to H_1(V)\to \ldots$$
Note that $H_2(V)=H_1(V)=0$ since  $V$ is  contractible. This  implies that $$H_{2}( V,V\setminus \{0\}) \cong H_1(V\setminus \{0\})$$
This  is  a  contradiction since the  left hand  side  is $0$ being the  second  homology of  $S^4$. The  RHS is $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}}$ because you have  a  2  sheet  covering space $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{0\} \to V\setminus\{0\}$ this implies that $\pi_1(V\setminus \{0\})=\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}}$. Hence its  first homology is the same by Hurewicz theorem

I can't believe I missed something so straightforward for why $V(z_1 z_2 - z_3^2) \setminus {0}$ is connected. I even wrote down in my working out that $\pi$ was surjective and continuous that and that $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus {0}$ was connected!

@MathsMatador Yes I see. I had guessed so

@MathsMatador  a point about your question: what is the algebraic geometric way?irreducibility of $ab-c^2$. The Variete you mentioned is the determinant of a symmetric matrix. So  this remind me of a result which say "determinant is an irreducible polynomial in n^2 variable

Yes, the algebraic geometry way I thought of is applying this which makes my exercise a trivial one if one can use this fact.
